# Simple / Fast way to calculate the period of a arbitrary polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, information-theory

If I get a polynomial, say $u^5 + u^4 + u^2 + 1$, what is a simple and fast (by which I mean not to much to write) way to get the period of this term?

Should I first test whether the polynomial is primitive?

*Edit*
By period I mean the smallest number $r$ such that $(u^r + 1) : p(u)$ can be done without a remainder. I **should definitely mention that all this is done as a modulus calculation**. So $u^5 + u^4 + u^3 + u^3 +u^2 +1 $ is exactly the same as the first example (i.e., there is no $2u^3$)

Comment: Period?? Modulo something, or what?

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. I hope this explains what I need.

Comment: @DanielOertwig Do you mean remainder instead of rest?

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, of course, sorry!

Comment: I don't think there is a simple, fast way to get the order of polynomials in ${\bf Z}_2[x]/(x^r+1)$ by hand.